# How do I make a script to set object index for every object?

Tags: python, scripting, id-mask

I wat to make a script that will, for every mesh in the scene, set a different object pass index so I don't have to select every mesh in my scene to assign a different number. I know this is possible via scripting, but I have no idea how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be:

```
import bpy

pi = 0
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.pass_index = pi
    pi += 1
```